# Проблема с запуском HBase (Windows)

Tags: база-данных, shell

Доброго времени суток всем! Столкнулся с проблемой запуска консоли HBase после установки на Windows 10 - вылетает следующая ошибка

```
C:\HBase\hbase-1.4.11\bin>hbase shell
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.java.invokers.RubyToJavaInvoker (file:/C:/HBase/hbase-1.4.11/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar) to method java.lang.Object.registerNatives()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.java.invokers.RubyToJavaInvoker
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
  method_added at file:/C:/HBase/hbase-1.4.11/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/javasupport/core_ext/object.rb:10
  method_added at file:/C:/HBase/hbase-1.4.11/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/javasupport/core_ext/object.rb:129
       Pattern at file:/C:/HBase/hbase-1.4.11/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/java/java.util.regex.rb:2
        (root) at file:/C:/HBase/hbase-1.4.11/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/java/java.util.regex.rb:1
       require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1062
        (root) at file:/C:/HBase/hbase-1.4.11/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/java/java.util.regex.rb:42
        (root) at C:\HBase\hbase-1.4.11\bin\..\bin\hirb.rb:38
```

Такая же ошибка встречается и после установки на Ubuntu или Linux Mint. Устанавливал несколько раз, использовал разные версии Java/HBase/Hadoop. Буду очень признателен за помощь в решении!

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка говорит о том, что [в java устарела опция UseConcMarkSweepGC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52239570/useconcmarksweepgc-is-deprecated-what-is-its-replacement). Можно поправить [скрипты/окружение](https://github.com/apache/hbase/search?q=UseConcMarkSweepGC&unscoped_q=UseConcMarkSweepGC) и вычистить оттуда эту опцию. Или заменить на UseG1GC. Почитайте так-же `man java`